# PHP Regex doesn't work in JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have following regex expression which is not working in JQuery but working fine in php version

What am I doing wrong?

**Expression**

```
if\s*\(((?:[^\(\)]|\((?1)\))*+)\)\s*{((?:[^{}]|{(?2)})*+)}
```

[php link](https://regex101.com/r/qP1eX8/1)

[Jquery Link](https://regex101.com/r/qP1eX8/2)

Comment: regex101 actually tells you which features are not supported in the JS regex engine. It's now about looking up how to do those in a different way, or if the syntax is different.

Comment: `(?1)` is a subroutine call not available in JS.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with this regex

Comment: `Invalid group, character '1' after '?' at column 23` as you can see if you input it into http://regen.io/

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not a universal language. You are using some constructs only available in PHP/PCRE (see what I changed below) and not JavaScript.

This regex is about the same, working in either version: `if\s*\(((?:[^\(\)]|\((\1)\))*)\)\s*{((?:[^{}]|{(\2)})*)}`

## What I changed

`(?1)` becomes `(\1)` (same with 2)

`*+` becomes `*`

---

Note:  I removed the backtracking control sequence: `*+`, so I wouldn't be surprised if this catastrophically backtracks with some inputs.